# fstab using login user credential

Tags: ubuntu, cifs

I'm building an ltsp server

All is well and is connected to my AD Server. I can login using the AD user.

My question here is how to make it mount a specific smb share from the server using the login credential a.k.a AD account ( means it's dynamic ). So when each user login it will automatically mount the smb share using their user.

Any good tutorial ?, what I find in the website mostly we have to write the user name and password in the file at let fstab read it, that's impossible .... for security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the samba mount [command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137011/how-to-mount-a-samba-shared-folder-ubuntu-x-ubuntu) as an [executable](http://www.linfo.org/create_shell_1.html) in one of your $PATH folders, you can find them trough

```
echo $PATH
```

for example the /usr/local/bin is usaly in the $PATH.
an example samba mount file:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo smbmount //192.168.2.28/projects /mnt/projects -o user=$1
```

So now you have a /usr/local/bin/mountsamba.sh, To let anyone run this:

```
# chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/mountsamba.sh
```

The third step is to allow the newly created executable to be executed as root without password, this requires editing of the sudoers file:

```
#visudo
```

and add:

```
%samba_mount_group ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/mountsamba.sh
```

now all users can in the samba_mount_group can execute that command as sudo without password.
you probalby also want to

- create a group: linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd
- add an user to a group: www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/

finaly to mount the folder on user login put the command in the target user's .bashrc

```
$ echo "cur_user=$USER; sudo bash /usr/local/bin/mountsamba.sh $cur_user" >> .bashrc
```

(note: this should be executed as the target user)
assuming they boot in the bourne again shell terminal